# captureFromWidget returns black image in screenshot library

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code

I'm trying to capture QrImage using screenshot package specifically .captureFromWidget method, I'm not building the widget QrImage, because I don't want to show it just print it out using the sumni_printer package.

I tried to show the QR before printing when it was an image, and it showed flawsly as it is.

here's the code:

```
Future<Uint8List> getQRBytes(String data) async {
  QrImage qr = QrImage(
    data: data,
    size: 100,
  );
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
  Screenshot(
    controller: screenshotController,
    child: qr,
  );
  Uint8List bytes = await screenshotController.captureFromWidget(qr);
  return bytes;
}
```

and the results when printed in sumni printer:

[image: how it's printed]

this is how I import the Uint8List when printing:

```
Uint8List qr = await getQRBytes(data);
await SunmiPrinter.printImage(qr);
```

here's how it looks in the app
[image: When showed in App]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's the sunmi_printer package...

there's a new package, [sunmi_printer_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sunmi_printer_plus)
it solved my issue and it's an amazing package

Comment: another fix was to wrap the `QRImage` inside the `Screenshot` widget into a `Container` providing a white background